# How to make password checker in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, passwords

I'm trying to make a simple password checker in Python.
The program asks the user to input a password with more than 8 letters/symbols and with a if/else statement and if it doesn't contain upper/lower letters and numbers but every time I input something it prints "Password is strong enough" even if I don't put upper/lower letter or number. So if someone can help me I would be thankful.

This is code:

```
password = input("Input your password: ")

if (len(password)<8):
  print("Password isn't strong enough")
elif not ("[a-z]"):
  print("Password isn't strong enough")
elif not ("[A-Z]"):
  print("Passsword isn't strong enough")
elif not ("[0-9]"):
  print("Password isn't strong enough")
else:
  print("Password is strong enough")
```

Comment: Think about what `not ("[a-z]")` is doing.  First, the parentheses serve no purpose here, so it's just `not "[a-z]"`.  So the `not` operator is being applied to a string.  Since the string is non-empty, it is considered to be true, so `not "[a-z]"` evaluates to `False`.  So all of the `elif` statements are equivalent to `elif False:`.  Note that they do not reference `password` at all, so `password` is only being used for the initial length check.

Comment: `elif not ("[a-z]")` It seems like you intended this code to check if the password contains any lowercase letters, but that is _not_ what this code is actually doing.

Comment: If you are running under Linux, you might want to look into PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules), It is a complex system, but allows to abstract such stuff into configuration files. It is (slowly) being adopted by [X/Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open) as a standard.

Comment: In your own words, exactly what rule do you think is implemented by doing `elif not ("[a-z]"):`? According to what logic?

Answer (score 2):

This check:

```
elif not ("[a-z]"):
```

does not do anything; it's just checking the truth value of a static string.  Since `"[a-z]"` is a non-empty string, it is always considered true (or "truthy"), which means `not "[a-z]"` will always be False no matter what's in `password`.  You might be meaning to use the `re` module, which you can read about here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Here's a way you might implement this checking without regexes, using Python's `all` and `any` functions, its `in` keyword, and the `string` module that contains handy strings like `ascii_lowercase` (all the lowercase letters, corresponding to the regex character class `[a-z]`):

```
import string

password = input("Input your password: ")

if all([
    len(password) >= 8,
    any(c in password for c in string.ascii_lowercase),
    any(c in password for c in string.ascii_uppercase),
    any(c in password for c in string.digits),
]):
    print("Password is strong enough")
else:
    print("Password is not strong enough")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply like this with the regex and it will work fine:

```
import re
password = input("Input your password: ")

if (re.match(r"^.*[A-Z]", password) and re.match(r"^.*[0-9]", password) and len(password)>7 and re.match(r"^.*[a-z]", password) ):   
    print("Password is strong enough")
else:
    print("Password is not strong enough")
```